# Grasils 3 - F5 load balancer- logout

Tags: grails, tomcat7, load-balancing, f5

I have 3 tomcats behind loadbalancer F5. I know that this is NOT a Sticky loadbalancer And i don't have a option to change F5 nor Tomcat configuration.

I login to my site and at random i get logged out. Is this because F5 sends me to another server? If Yes, Is there anything i can do in the code to prevent this?

```
JVM Version: 1.8.0_72 
Grails Version: 3.1.1
Tomcat 7
compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
```

Comment: Session replication between your tomcat instances.

Comment: It is a Shared environment so they won't let me change any configuration in F5 nor in Tomcat.  Do i have any other option?

Comment: Not that I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

if by sticky you mean persistence, then that is completely configurable on the f5, by source or destination ip, cookie session persistence, or you can roll your own by persisting on anything in the payload via iRules.

--missed the "I can't change the f5" config in your question. If you are able to get an understanding of the existing configuration on the f5, there might be some things you can do in code.